# Is an a.e finite function integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

It is known that an integrable function is a.e. finite. Is an a.e. finite function integrable?  What if the measure is finite?

Comment: The function $f(x) = 1$ is finite for all $x\in\Bbb R$ but it's not integrable on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 15):

No.  A characteristic function of a non measurable set is everywhere finite, but not integrable.

Answer (score 12):

No, just consider the constant function $1$. It is not integrable on the real line.

You don't even need an unbounded domain. Let $f(x) = \frac 1x$ and integrate over $[0,1]$ to find a counterexample to your statement.

Answer (score 5):

No. $\frac{1}{x}$ is an example.